# QuickType capitalises words unnecessarily

Tags: ios, autocorrect

Quite some time ago, QuickType started capitalising the word "long" into "Long", even if it was not the first word in the sentence. This issue has begun to affect more than the word long, and a few are mentioned below:

```
long -> Long
low -> Low
cricket -> Cricket
teachers -> Teachers
```

There are many more, but they are too many to list and don't exactly contribute to the purpose of this question.

I don't usually capitalise these words, some of them I have never used before (in the case of "cricket"), but they are just capitalised *like that*.

Is there any logical explanation as to why QuickType seems to be capitalising these words as and when it pleases?

Answer (score 1):

While I can't provide an explanation as to why this is happening, if this is really bothering you I recommend resetting the keyboard dictionary.  This is the 'nuclear option' for keyboard problems but it looks like you've tried everything else already.

To do this, go to `Settings -> General -> Reset` and tap on `“Reset Keyboard Dictionary”`.  Be care you tap the correct link here because you can accidentally reset a bunch of other parts of your iPhone, including Network or the entire iPhone.  Confirm you want to reset the dictionary and it will be wiped back to the factory defaults.

This will erase any and all modifications you have made to the keyboard but it will not erase any shortcuts you created or contact list entry name/nicknames.